# mediaDevices.getUserMedia returns video rotated to landscape on some devices

Tags: javascript, webrtc, html5-video, getusermedia

I'm using getUserMedia to get a video stream, on some devices it returns video in portrait mode (as i want it to be) but on some video is in landscape.

for example on iPhone XR and Redmi Note 12 video is portrait, on iPhone 14 pro and Google Pixel 6 it's in landscape

This was my initial code

```
const getVideo = () => {
    const isDesktop = window.screen.width > window.screen.height;
    if(navigator){
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        video: {
      aspectRatio: isDesktop ? 9 / 16 : 16 / 9,
      facingMode: "environment",
      width: {  ideal: 2160 },
      height: { ideal: 4096 },
        },
      })
      .then((stream) => {
        console.log('started stream')
        const video = videoRef;
        video.srcObject = stream;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`[Event] Error: ${err}`);
      });
    }
  };
```

Which works exactly as i expect it to work on both devices that i have and on desktops, but gives rotated video on some devices reason of which i was not able to identify.

I've tried different variations of constraints but none of them give the same result on different devices, best result so far is with:

```
 .getUserMedia({
          video: {
            facingMode: "environment",
             width: isDesktop ? { ideal: 2196} : { ideal: 3840 },
            height: isDesktop ? { ideal: 3840 } : { ideal: 2196 },
          },
        })
```

But on devices where video would be flipped to landscape with this settings it looks like it is zoomed in to fill the screen instead of taken in portrait mode in the first place.

Same happens if setting `aspectRatio: {exact: 1.5}`

Comment: Try removing this header from the SDP `urn:3gpp:video-orientation`.